# Wash sale rule impact of overall cost basis of long term investment

Tags: stocks, wash-sale

I'm new to investing and did not know there was a wash sale rule. I bought a stock as I had thought it was at its bottom and sold as it continued to drop. I then bought the stock back later as it  reached its potential bottom. The wash sale rule applied of course. I plan to hold this stock long term. If I continue to add shares will my cost per share average down from the wash sale?

Comment: Is this about the US?

Comment: This depends on the applicable tax law. Can you [edit] your question to include where in the world you are so we know what rules apply?

Comment: @quid - I have incorporated our comments into my answer :->)

Answer (score 2):

A wash sale has no effect on the cost basis of your overall position or on your P&L. It only affects your ability to claim realized losses in any given tax year.

While IRS language says that wash sale losses are *disallowed*, technically, they are *deferred* until you close the replacement share position without a subsequent wash sale violation. The one exception is if you make the error involving a non-sheltered and a sheltered account. Then, the loss deduction can be lost completely.

The consequences of a sizable wash sale carryover violation can be significant. Suppose you make $10k from trading this year ($100k in gains and $90k in losses) and suppose $40k of those losses are a carryover wash sale violation, deferred until next year. You will have to pay taxes on $50k this year.

Making matters worse, if you don't have MTM Tax Trader Status, you  will be limited to deducting $3k per year of that carryover loss if you don't have capital gains next year as well as in any subsequent year where the remaining carryover loss exceed  $3k.

As a precaution, evaluate all of your trades toward the end of the year (I do it at the end of November).  If you have any wash sale violations of size, understand that if you close the replacement share position before the end of the year and you do not acquire substantially identical shares within 30 day (including in January) the you will have none of the aforementioned problems.

Also note that when you close a short sale at a loss, tax law treats the transaction as occurring on the settlement date so make sure that your closing transaction date leaves enough time for settlement within the same calendar year.

Comment: I have no idea who would vote this down...

Comment: @quid My only guess is that it was because this answer assumes US jurisdiction while the question does not specify which country (although to be fair, there was a united-states tag on the question at the time the answer was written, so that would be a little ridiculous)

Comment: @yoozer8 - My answer assumes US jurisdiction because the question does not specify which country when in fact, you're the one who removed the United States tag?  Got it. That makes perfect sense.  LOLOL

Comment: @BobBaerker I removed it because it was added by a third party and appeared to be a guess at what country is being asked about. Location tags [should not be added in such a manner](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2110/guidelines-for-asking-for-editing-country-tags-in-questions-from-new-users). (I did not downvote your answer)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link to an excellent "plain english" explanation [Wash Sale Rule Explained](https://www.thebalance.com/the-wash-sale-rule-356081) as well as one from Fidelity that is generally good too [Fidelity Wash Sale Rule](https://www.fidelity.com/learning-center/personal-finance/wash-sales-rules-tax)

The wash sale rule applies to the 30 days before you sell as well as 30 days after you sell. So there's a 61 day period that is important.

If you violate the wash sale rule, the most obvious impact is you cannot deduct the loss resulting from the sale.  What people tend to overlook or forget is that while you can't deduct the loss, you can add the loss amount to the cost basis of the repurchased tax lot.[image: Simple Example]

You can also add the holding period of the original investment to the holding period of the replacement. So to answer your question, your repurchase cost basis is increased by the loss amount; any additional purchases are treated normally and adjust your total cost basis based on the cost of those additional purchases

Comment: What is that table supposed to represent?

Comment: It looks like an incomplete attempt to demonstrate a wash sale violation and the adjustment of the replacement shares.